# toUpperCase(); - exception: The method toUpperCase() is undefined for the type Pseudo

Tags: java

Here is the code for my program. The main method was provided and cannot be touched. The main method converts a String to uppercase but does not accept the toUpperCase(); java method. How can I solve this problem without altering my main method?

```
public class Pseudo {

String name;
char charArray[] = new char[80];
int lenghtOfString =0;
String sArray;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Instantiate class        
    Pseudo pseudo = new Pseudo();

    // Verify class
    System.out.println("Verifying Pseudo:");
    pseudo.setString("1234567890 Computer Science !(*@&#)*&");
    System.out.println("pseudo = " + pseudo.getString());
    System.out.println("pseudo.charAt(5) = " + pseudo.charAt(5));
    System.out.println("pseudo.indexOf('C') = " + pseudo.indexOf('C'));
    System.out.println("pseudo.toUpperCase() = " + pseudo.toUpperCase());
    System.out.println("pseudo.substring(11, 19) = " + pseudo.substring(11, 19));
    pseudo.setString("Compare");
    System.out.println("pseudo.equals(\"Compare\") = " + pseudo.equals("Compare"));
    System.out.println("pseudo.equals(\"Compare!\") = " + pseudo.equals("Compare!"));

    // String equivalent (should match!)
    System.out.println("\nComparing String:");
    String string = "1234567890 Computer Science !(*@&#)*&";
    System.out.println("string = " + string);
    System.out.println("string.charAt(5) = " + string.charAt(5));
    System.out.println("string.indexOf('C') = " + string.indexOf('C'));
    System.out.println("string.toUpperCase() = " + string.toUpperCase());
    System.out.println("string.substring(11, 19) = " + string.substring(11, 19));
    string = "Compare";
    System.out.println("string.equals(\"Compare\") = " + string.equals("Compare"));
    System.out.println("string.equals(\"Compare!\") = " + string.equals("Compare!"));
}

public void setString(String s1){
    name=s1;
}
public String getString() {
    return name;
}
public char charAt(int i1) {
    return name.charAt(i1);
}
public int indexOf(char c1) {
    return name.indexOf(c1);
}
public String substring(int start, int end) {
    return name.substring(start,end);
}
public boolean equals(String s2) {
    if (s2 == name){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
} 
}
```

I understand that I could create a method named toUpperCase to run the .toUpperCase method. But could you explain why you have to create a method to run .toUpperCase(); method java has it already in its library? Why could the .toUpperCase(); method not work the same in main?

Comment: `Pseudo` doesn't provide a `toUpperCase`-method. Why would you even use a wrapper-class for this kind of purpose?

Comment: You've not defined a method called `toUpperCase` in your `Pseudo` class, for example, you've created a method called `indexOf` in your `Pseudo` class, but no `toUpperCase` method.  You can not call what is not there

Comment: Don't use the `toUppercase()` method. You should use `toUppercase(Locale.ENGLISH)`.

Comment: Also, your equals method can cause unknown behavior. Never use == in Java when comparing non-primitives. The following is JRE dependent, but if both strings were created in a way where it would've used the string pool  then they will both reference the same memory, however all it takes is someone to call new String() and you will get undefined behavior. To see this try this: `System.out.println("pseudo.equals(new String(\"Compare\")) = " + pseudo.equals(new String("Compare")));` vs `System.out.println("string.equals(new String(\"Compare\")) = " + string.equals(new String("Compare")));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explainatory. You don't have a method `toUpperCase()` for your `Pseudo` class.

So add a method `toUpperCase` to your `Pseudo` class:

```
public String toUpperCase()
{
    return name.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I understand that I could create a method named toUpperCase to run the .toUpperCase method. But could you explain why you have to create a method to run .toUpperCase(); method java has it already in its library? Why could the .toUpperCase(); method not work the same in main?

Comment: The method that java has is for String class and when you call `pseudo.toUpperCase()` you are trying to call it for class `Pseudo` for which it doesn't exists. So that is why you need to create one.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `toUpperCase` method to your `Pseudo` class.